# Remove message from an iMessage extension programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, imessage, imessage-extension

Is there a way to remove the message that is coming from an iMessage extension programmatically?

**SCENARIO**: When the recipient has read the message coming from the extension, the message will be deleted automatically after a few seconds.

Preferably, the deletion of message will be handled programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely no way to edit, remove any messages, even if they are coming from your app extension. Once they are in the conversation you cannot do anything more, sorry :/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
layout.caption = "My Message"

let message = MSMessage()
message.layout = layout   
message.shouldExpire = true

self.activeConversation?.insertText("Test", completionHandler: nil)
```

The specific line that you want is `message.shouldExpire = true`.